# Android Service makes application Hangs

Tags: android, service

Here is my Issue:

In my app there is a scenario like app automatically detects the ultra sound which intern contain some information in it.And this sound should be played in Retail shope while user enter into shop my app should detect the sound which is playing in every entrance of the Store.

So for this I created one Service by extending Service class,which always keep on running.And  I am started this service from Activity by creating a separate thread 
for it.

**Here is my Problem:**

**When I started a service from thread it working fine and no UI is hanged.After some time when i still deal with the UI then my app got hanged and i got ANR error in the log cat.**

So how do I resolve this issue.

satrting service from thread is the correct way..?
Any good approach for start the service.?
How can i resolve the ANR eror from my code.?

Can any one please Help me in this. I tried for so many posts but any one is not worked for me.

Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask will solve the purpose. You should do vice versa. You can start service from main UI thread as well , and the task right now you are doing in Service , you can do it in separate thread. And you can Start the Thread from Service.

So It should be - Activity --> Service --> Thread  You can also use AsyncTask , which is nothing but a background thread.

Regards,
Brijesh

Comment: Hi brijesh, In my case: I have Activity-->Thread(From where I start the service)-->Service-->Thread(Where am doing funcionlaity infinately). while thread is running infinately am able to deal with the app UI.But after some time the app got hanged.

Comment: First thing you should do is , Activity --> Thread --> Service. Remove Thread part from it. Because I see there is no need of Thread which will save your process. Other thing can you please paste the ANR stack track. I want to see the reason for getting ANR. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Brijesh, Without Thread in service how can I listen for Ultra sound ,detect and Decode it. In my case Service should be keep on running beause app should not know when the user enter into store.So is it possible to run the service continueosly without thread. Please keep in touch with me.

Comment: Yes Poorna , each service has a life cycle. So Once you start service ,It will keep running in background. If you want to check whether service is running or not , You can go and check in Settings -- > Applications --> Running Services --> And you can see All the running services.  Only thing that you are doing is right. Service will invoke a thread to perform a task.  Just paste the stack trace of ANR that you are getting. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Brijesh.I removed the thread part.Witout thread also I am getting ANR. Please find the stacktrace here.08-22 14:56:01.599: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): ANR in com.internal.britefone
08-22 14:56:01.599: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): Reason: Executing service com.internal.britefone/.soundservice.MyService_32Bit
08-22 14:56:01.599: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): Load: 7.58 / 7.3 / 7.13
08-22 14:56:01.599: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): CPU usage from

Comment: Insteadof Thread now I am using AsycTask in that case I am Getting ANR as follows when I am using my app.08-22 15:55:04.511: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): ANR in com.internal.britefone (com.internal.britefone/.BritefoneTabActivity)
08-22 15:55:04.511: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
08-22 15:55:04.511: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): Load: 5.72 / 5.71 / 6.03
08-22 15:55:04.511: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424): CPU usage from 236007ms to 31ms ago:
08-22 15:55:04.511: ERROR/ActivityManager(1424):   system_server: 18% = 11% user + 7% kernel / faults:

Comment: KeyDispatchingTimedOut is coming because  ,After calling service , Activity is waiting for Response till 5 seconds. And if it doesn't Android System will throw ANR. Make Sure you call Service from Activity and  OnStart method should return back to activity within 5 seconds. To debug that , you just comment the code of Async Task in Service.  And Moreover , You should Start a new Thread from Service. you can revert your code :). Thanks :)

Comment: You can probably use , Broadcast receiver to start your service. In that case you will get 10 seconds to start your task. :) Try that , Will solve your purpose. Thanks :)

Comment: Activity-->BroadcastReceiver-->Service-->Thread in this way am using now.Service started successfully and runs in the background .I am able to naviagate some of the screens upto 2-4 minutes.After that app got hanged & crahed,giving ANR KeyDispatchingTimedOut error.In my service i have while(true) loop to keep on checking the sound detection.Thanks for giving your support

Comment: Your While True loop call should come under thread. I guess that will solve your purpose